# How to delete records from database table older than 30 days with based on date column

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-delete, sqldatetime

This is the code in python that i am using below. But its not working and not showing any error.

```
delquery = "DELETE FROM table1 WHERE date_column < date ('now', '-30 day')"        
conn.execute(delquery)
```

I am using SQLite Database.

Comment: What is the format of the `date_column` column?

Comment: perhaps you forgot to commit since there's no issue with the format.

Comment: @forpas. Date format is yyyy/MM/dd application. In the database text type.

Comment: @Barbaros Özhan. I am using  conn.commit() after conn.execute(delquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the format is `yyyy/MM/dd` you must change it to `yyyy-MM-dd`, because this is the only valid comparable format for dates in SQLite:

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE REPLACE(date_column, '/', '-') < date('now', '-30 day')
```

Or even better update the table, so `date_column` is in the proper format and you don't need the function `REPLACE()` every time you want to compare dates:

```
UPDATE table1
SET date_column = REPLACE(date_column, '/', '-')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @end date = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1)

DELETE FROM table1 WHERE date_column < @end
```

Comment: Thank you for your Response. Is this statement work for SQLite i am using SQLite DB. I added your code but its not working.

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.